# Add new column with strsplit

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df, it looks like :

```
                               V1              V2      V3
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 10:00  11,390
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 11:00  11,830
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 12:00  12,370
2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02)  03/12/15 13:00  14,550
2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02)  03/12/15 14:00  15,510
3 - SIERRA MIJAS3 (MA)3- (001M02)  03/12/15 15:00  15,220
```

I need to add a new column in base of the first token of the first column.
I mean, i need something like that:

```
                               V1              V2      V3 New
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 10:00  11,390 1
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 11:00  11,830 1
1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)  03/12/15 12:00  12,370 1
2 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA)2- (001M02)  03/12/15 13:00  14,550 2
2 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA)2- (001M02)  03/12/15 14:00  15,510 2
3 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA)3- (001M02)  03/12/15 15:00  15,220 3
```

I tried something like that:

```
df$New<-strsplit(df[,1]," ")[[1]][1]
```

But I got the same value for any row : "1".

Is there any simple way to figure out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it with `strsplit`:

```
#strsplit returns a list so you need a function like sapply to 
#extract the first element from each vector of each element of the list
df$New <- sapply(strsplit(df[,1], ' '), '[', 1)
```

Output:

```
> df
                                 V1             V2     V3 New
1 1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02) 03/12/15 10:00 11,390   1
2 1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02) 03/12/15 11:00 11,830   1
3 1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02) 03/12/15 12:00 12,370   1
4 2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02) 03/12/15 13:00 14,550   2
5 2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02) 03/12/15 14:00 15,510   2
6 3 - SIERRA MIJAS3 (MA)3- (001M02) 03/12/15 15:00 15,220   3
```

Data:

```
df<-read.table(header=T, text='                             V1              V2      V3
"1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)"  "03/12/15 10:00"  11,390
           "1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)"  "03/12/15 11:00"  11,830
           "1 - SIERRA MIJAS  (MA) - (001M02)"  "03/12/15 12:00"  12,370
           "2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02)"  "03/12/15 13:00"  14,550
           "2 - SIERRA MIJAS2 (MA)2- (001M02)"  "03/12/15 14:00"  15,510
           "3 - SIERRA MIJAS3 (MA)3- (001M02)"  "03/12/15 15:00"  15,220')
```

Comment: It will be usefull if the first token allways have one character lenght. But it havent. It could be "1" or "430" in other rows.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer with `strsplit` then that would work with different numbers.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly... I have some warnings because there are some spanish characters like "ó" "á" "ñ", that R doesnt like, and in those rows, the new column is NA .. But any way. my main issue was solved. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome, glad I could be of help :) . It seems a bit strange though that it wouldn't work with Spanish characters. I replaced one of the numbers with 'ó' and it seems to be working here: `> sapply(strsplit(df[,1], ' '), '[', 1)
[1] "1" "ó" "1" "2" "2" "3"`

Comment: I have these warnings in rows :
7 - DEPÓSITO DI-1 (CA) - (007M02); 03/12/15 10:00; 13,710

16 - EMBALSE DE LA CONCEPCIÓN (MA) - (016M02); 03/12/15
10:00; 11,640

22 - MÁLAGA - PALACIO DE LA TINTA (MA) - (022M02); 03/12/15 10:00; 13,420

Maybe, because is special spanish characters in upper case, im not sure.

Comment: I don't see any warnings there to be honest. Maybe you can try debugging on your own and if not you can always post a new question :)

Comment: Ok. Ill do it.. Thanks you so much.